# How to crontab a R-script and append the errors

Tags: r

I'm new to `Ubuntu` and would like to run a daily `crontab`. I'm running similar job under `Windows Command Line` but would like to switch to `Ubuntu`.

My `R-Script` has an `Error-function` which prints errors into a separate
folder everytime a job is done and an error has occured ():

```
 # define error function
 my.error.fun <- function() {
 cat(geterrmessage(), file="/home/network/R/Test.txt", append=TRUE)
} 

# output error
options("error"=my.error.fun)
```

Under `crontab -e` I have determined the following:

```
00 16 * * * /usr/bin/Rscript /home/R/network/Test.R 2> /home/R/RErrors/Test.txt
```

and the `crontab`has been saved under `/tmp/crontab.2t/crontab`

where I append the errros inside the R-Script. In contrast to `Windows Command Line` that concept seems not to work in `Ubuntu` That seems not to work however. I'm not sure whether thats the correct syntax. There has been no file in the `RErrors` folder.

May I as for some suggestions?

Comment: You are telling to `crontab` to execute the job exactly at 16 (4PM). Is that what you want?

Comment: Hi Nicola, yes thats what I want

Comment: Was asking just to be sure that the "not working" wasn't due to the fact that the job isn't executed at all yet.

Comment: :) I had a similar idea...tried as well

Comment: Are you sure that there is no file produced in RErrors folder because if no file is produced then the script haven't been running. Linux produce error file (empty) even if no error occurred. Try `echo 1 2> /home/R/RErrors/Test1.txt` it should produce empty `Test1.txt` file.

Comment: `echo`produced the output as desired. Thank you!!

Comment: So the problem resolved? How did the cron command looked like in the end?

Comment: Yes, it works. As suggested `echo 1 2>` and the Errors has referenced a missing `library`which I havent loaded to test the Script.

Comment: @user974514 can you answer the question with your solution? It will help future solution-seekers from having to dig through all the comments.